# Notation: How to condition on specific elements of a vector?

Tags: summation, notation

I have a vector $\mathbf{s}=(s_{aa},s_{ab},s_{ba},s_{bb})$ of length $I$. 
Now I would like to sum over all elements of $\mathbf{s}$ that have $a$ in the $k^{th}$ position of the subscript.

So, if $k=1$, I would like to have the sum $s_{aa} + s_{ab}$.
In sum notation, I would have to condition the index of $\mathbf{s}$ on the value of $k$: 
$\sum_{i}^{I} \mathbf{s}$

Is there general notation for $i$? Or do I have to express the condition in words?

Comment: You can always mimic if-conditions by using [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) or [indicator functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)... whether or not it is *worth* doing like this is another matter entirely.

Comment: As for your specific use-case... Are you hard-set on treating your "vector" as it is written above?  It may be much easier to treat it like in computer science as an array of arrays, or in math as a matrix.  It is quite obvious how to describe summing a particular row of a matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} s_{aa}&s_{ab}\\s_{ba}&s_{bb}\end{smallmatrix}\right]$

Comment: Thank you for your input. Good point. I am considering array notation (given that my problem has more than the two dimensions I described). But basically, my problem then changes to: "How to write down over which array dimension to sum?" If $k=1$, and should have value $a$, then I should sum over all rows $a$. If $k=2$, I should sum over all columns $a$. If $k=3$ however, I have to sum over matrix slice $a$, etc. So, I still do not really have a clue about general notation for $k$. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Are you trying to program with this?  Or merely write about this on paper?  If trying to program, it is a simple matter of loops and nested arrays and properly defining your switch cases for what each value of $k$ should represent.  If trying to write on paper, it may be easier to just use words.

Comment: No, I'm writing: it is purely about notation. I know how to program this.